# Wrong number of data values in record

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradata-covalent

I have some tab delimited files that I am importing from a folder using SQL Assistant. These files each have more than 200 thousand records, when I try to insert them, I get the error message 'Wrong number of data values in record', I have tried importing 10,000 at a time and they insert. Is there a way I can insert a whole file with over 200 thousand records?

Comment: There's probably some bad data, try *Tools > Options > Import > Silently discard rows that cause constraint violations* (and increase *Maximum batch size for simple imports*). Or switch to Teradata Studio or a real load utility like TPT

Comment: Thanks, I have just tried the silently discard rows that cause constraint violations and i am still having the problem. I checked the 9478 and found out that the pattern of how the data appears on the file is offset. There are some double quotes and one line(row) is too long and continued in the next row and occuppied about 1/4 of the second line and the remaining of that line is blank.